# How to Use Spring Security OAuth in Cluster Environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using `InMemoryTokenStore` which is not working in Clustered environment. I have to store token in a place from where we can easily access it in cluster environment.

I can't use `JdbcTokenStore`, as I don't have the access of database. 
I want to use either 'Ehcache' or 'RedisTokenStore'. Please help me which is better approach and how I can use it.

Comment: Ckeck out my answer. Please accept if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> First of all you have a clustered environment which means, your
>   application is handling serious business logic.

Raplicating the `inMemory` data from one `servlet container` to another is really *expensive*. Good thing is you have realized to move up for a better solution.

> EhCache is a used to maintain cache across all the nodes in a
>   clustered environment.
>
> EhCache in itself is not a type of cache and is just a tool. Also,
>   EhCache doesn't not maintain the cache, it just triggers some of the
>   actions/services across the nodes so that each node can
>   re-fresh/update its own cache.

- The techniques used for dealing with the cache coherency issues
  across the cluster nodes include:
- Pull data from the store (DB) every time it is needed (no caching.) In general, it is an expensive operation and has
  performance implications in a multi-user web based application.
- Keep local caches up to date by polling and refreshing at a pre-configured interval.
- Replicating the cache data across the cluster nodes.
- Keep the local caches up-to-date based on a Distributed Event that notifies the members of the cluster of the changes.

> Redis works really well in distributed environment, especially with
>   [Redis Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) and [Redis Cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial). My suggestion is go with
>   [Redis](http://redis.io/documentation)

These tutorials will help you to understand the implementation:

- [Code review - Spring oauth2 token store supported by redis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88498/spring-oauth2-token-store-supported-by-redis)
- [Scaling out with Spring Session](http://www.jayway.com/2015/05/31/scaling-out-with-spring-session/)
- [GitHub - RedisSessionRegistry](https://github.com/tomekkup/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-redis/src/main/java/com/kuprowski/redis/security/core/session/RedisSessionRegistry.java)

Comment: Additionally, you can explore JWT.

Answer (score 1):

I used in my clustered application the [Apache Ignite data grid](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-grid) which is an implementation of JCache (JSR 107) specification.

You can set up the cache in the following way:

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();
CacheConfiguration<CacheKey, Object> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<CacheKey, Object>(cacheName.toString());
cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
cacheCfg.setBackups(1);
cacheCfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
cacheCfg.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 604800)));
IgniteCache<CacheKey, Object> igniteCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
```

And then you can use the cache to get/put the OAuth2 access tokens as below:

```
igniteCache.get(key);
igniteCache.put(key, o);
```